# jump to search result in a repeat control with a pager control in a xpages

Tags: anchor, xpages

I created a search control in xpages, that works well. My problem now is how to create the link to open the result. Thats also working fine except when the result is in a xpages repeat control.
So my question is how can I jump directly to a specific site and to a specific doc on that site e.g. page-site 3 and there the 5th doc.
Is it possible to execute multiple anchor links (open the site, jump to the page in the repeat control and than to the doc ...).
If have the same 'issue' with my deep-links and with my tag-links.

Thanks
Armin

The code of the repeat looks something like this (I cleaned some bootstrap stuff out, hopefully not to much)

```
    <xp:dominoView var="viewSC" sortColumn="sorting"
        sortOrder="descending">
        <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (sessionScope.level2UNID == ""){
    return "HV3101";
}else{
    return "HV3201";
}}]]></xp:this.viewName>

        <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:var qString:String;
if (sessionScope.level2UNID != null & sessionScope.level2UNID != ""){
    qString = "(Field level2Key = \"" + sessionScope.level2UNID + "\")";
}else{
    qString = "(Field level1Key = \"" + sessionScope.level1UNID + "\")";
}
sessionScope.l3Query = qString;
return qString;}]]></xp:this.search>
    </xp:dominoView>


    <xp:panel id="contentRepeat" styleClass="content">
        <xp:repeat id="level3" rows="2" var="level3List"
            disableOutputTag="true" value="#{viewSC}" indexVar="L3X">
            <xp:panel id="repeatFrame" disableOutputTag="true">
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoDocument var="docL3" action="openDocument"
                        documentId="#{javascript:level3List.getNoteID()}"
                        ignoreRequestParams="true">
                    </xp:dominoDocument>
                </xp:this.data>

                <xp:panel id="anchor" tagName="a">
                    <xp:this.attrs>
                        <xp:attr name="name">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
docL3.getItemValueString("UniqueID");
}catch (e){
 sessionScope.L3Err = e;
}}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:attr>
                    </xp:this.attrs>
                </xp:panel>

                <xp:panel id="bsAccordion" styleClass="accordion">
                    <xp:div styleClass="accordion-group">
                        <xp:div styleClass="accordion-heading">
                            <xp:link escape="true" styleClass="accordion-toggle" id="toggleSubContent">
                                <xp:this.attrs>
                                    <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="collapse">
                                    </xp:attr>
                                    <xp:attr name="data-parent" value="##{id:bsAccordion}">
                                    </xp:attr>
                                </xp:this.attrs>
                                <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
if(level3List != null){
    var nd:NotesDocument = level3List.getDocument();
    if(nd != null){
        if(nd.getItemValueString("dspCreated") == "1"){
            var creationDate:NotesDateTime = nd.getItemValueDateTimeArray("created")[0];
            return " " + nd.getItemValueString("title") + " (Erstellt: " + creationDate.getDateOnly() + ")";
        }else{
            return " " + nd.getItemValueString("title");
        }       
    }
}
}catch(e){
    sessionScope.errorEx = e;
}}]]></xp:this.text>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:x$(getComponent("accordionCollapse").getClientId(facesContext))}]]></xp:this.value>
                                <i class="icon-minus"></i>
                            </xp:link>
                            <xp:link escape="true" id="link1" value="##{id:pager1}">
                                <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:"aP" + L3X}]]></xp:this.text>
                            </xp:link>
                        </xp:div>
                        <xp:panel styleClass="accordion-body collapse in" id="accordionCollapse">
                            <xp:div styleClass="accordion-inner">
                                <xp:panel id="subRTContent" styleClass="l3Content">
                                    <xp:inputRichText id="dspLevel3" value="#{docL3.content}"
                                        readonly="true" styleClass="l3Content">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:panel>
                                <xp:panel styleClass="contentFooter" id="contentSFooter">

                                        </xp:panel>
                            </xp:div>
                        </xp:panel>
                    </xp:div>
                </xp:panel>

            </xp:panel>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
```

Comment: Do you wish to go to jump to Page X, in pager control which is linked to your Repeat Control?

Comment: A code example is a little bit difficult. I have 3 'levels' of navigation (top-level, side-vavigation and content). Each of documents unid is stored in a sessionscope. So if I open up a document I set the 3 sessionscopes and compute the page. I will try my best to come up with something ...

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers that might help you to go ahead:

- stop paging in repeats. The extlib has a nice sample of "show more", so instead of showing 1-20, 21-40 etc. you show until the record you found (might not work for large datasets)
- Open the search page with URL parameters that indicate the position number of the document (e.g. 498). Then use that parameter to let the repeat control figure out the starting position (which depends on the number of documents the repeat is configured for (default is 30, but you don't know). Just make sure not to use the passed parameter unchecked.
- you can add `<a name="[unid]">` (or id=) tags to the repeat and then [directly navigate] (http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a) to them ....nsf/searchResults.xsp#unid?moreParameters

Let us know how it goes

Comment: To create an anchor tag for each repeated element is no problem, but how can I link to this? If the repeat creates to pages the anchor links from the second page are not computed. At least they are not visibile in the html. I don't get it at the moment.

Comment: Update your question with the code you have so far. Simplify it to get a minimum example that shows the problem - helps to get clarity. SO you have an anchor (check your source!) you link to it in the href argument yourpage.xsp#theanchor

Comment: Yes I have anchors and it works if they are on the same page ...xsp#anchor jumps to the contentet. But it doesn'T jump to a content which is on a different page. How should this workbecause I thought they will be 'computed' when I move to the next page ...

Comment: Got you.... you might need a little trickery in the URL then... have a parameter there that serves as the startkey for your repeat, so you jump to the right place